# VirtualBox connection to public WiFi via confirmation on the windows host machine

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, virtualbox, microsoft-edge

I have a Windows 10 machine and Virtual Box 6. I have installed Ubuntu and I am able to connect Ubuntu to the internet via NAT. But when I connect to a public WiFi such as Starbucks or library where i have to accept the connection in Windows Edge i cannot access the internet from the Ubuntu VM. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Open the **Settings** of the VM and click **Network**. On the drop-down menu where you selected "NAT" (labeled *Attached to*), change it to **Bridged Adapter**. FYI - this is not as secure, so make sure your Ubuntu firewall is running.

Comment: I  should qualify my question a bit. when the setting is Attached to : NAT either i can get to google once meaning when i open my firefox browser in Ubutnu i can get to google and search for something. But i cannot open any url and if i refresh the page i cannot get to google again, but firefox never comes back it just spins  waiting for www.google.com.  When i change the setting to Bridge Adapter (and restart). Immediately the browser comes back with you are not connected to the internet. and eventually i see the message "Cannot Connect to Network Adapter.

Comment: Go back into Network Settings, click the advanced arrow, and change promiscuous mode to "Allow All" (found on another answer here that was similar to your problem). If this doesn't work, I'll need to do more research. I don't have a laptop, so I have no way to test this in the real world.